# Merging data using left_join based on a condition

Tags: r

I have two data frames I am trying to merge.

"data" looks like:

```
    Filled_Ticker2LP publishYear              CO_1_Name
 1:             SONC        2005             sonic corp
 2:             SONC        2005             sonic corp
 3:             <NA>        2005   cascade bancorp inc.
 4:              JCP        2005  jc penney company inc
```

"comp" looks like:

```
   tic   fyear conm           
   <chr> <int> <chr>          
 1 JCP    2004 penney (j c) co
 2 JCP    2005 penney (j c) co
 3 JCP    2006 penney (j c) co
 4 JCP    2007 penney (j c) co
 5 JCP    2008 penney (j c) co
```

I want to join these two data sets together using `left_join` (or something from the `data.table` package etc.)

I can currently join it based on the year and symbol such as `SONC`, `JCP`.

```
mergedData <- data %>% 
  left_join(comp, by = c("Filled_Ticker2LP" = "tic", "publishYear" = "fyear"))
```

The "mergedData" looks like:

```
    Filled_Ticker2LP publishYear              CO_1_Name            conm
 1:             SONC        2005             sonic corp      sonic corp
 2:             SONC        2005             sonic corp      sonic corp
 3:             <NA>        2005   cascade bancorp inc.            <NA>
 4:              JCP        2005  jc penney company inc penney (j c) co
```

Which Works well but it has an `NA` in the `Filled_Ticker2LP` column (which comes from the `data` data set.

I would like to try and join the data using the current method that I have but if there is an `NA` value in the column `Filled_Ticker2LP` I would like to change the "matching link" from joining on `tic` and `Filled_Ticker2LP` to matching on company name. `conm` or `CO_1_Name`.

That is, the data fails to join currently because in the `data` data set under the column `Filled_Ticker2LP` for observation `3` it has an `NA` value. However, this observation can still be joined with the `comp` data since in the column `data$CO_1_Name` observation 3 has `cascade Bancorp`. This result also appears in the `comp` data from observation 30 - 53 under the column `conm`.

I was thinking of an `if` statement that:

> if not NA in data$Filled_Ticker2LP then join using Filled_Ticker2LP
>   and tic else join using CO_1_Name and conm.

Additional

I also noticed that there is some whitespace in the columns.

```
data %>% 
  mutate(
    CO_1_Name = str_trim(CO_1_Name)
  )
```

Data 1:

```
comp <- structure(list(tic = c("JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", 
"JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", 
"SONC", "SONC", "SONC", "SONC", "SONC", "SONC", "SONC", "SONC", 
"SONC", "SONC", "SONC", "SONC", "SONC", "SONC", "CACB", "CACB", 
"CACB", "CACB", "CACB", "CACB", "CACB", "CACB", "CACB", "CACB", 
"CACB", "CACB", "CACB", "CACB", "CACB", "CACB", "CACB", "CACB", 
"CACB", "CACB", "CACB", "CACB", "CACB", "CACB"), fyear = c(2004L, 
2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 
2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 
2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 
2018L, 2005L, 2005L, 2006L, 2006L, 2007L, 2007L, 2008L, 2008L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2010L, 2010L, 2011L, 2011L, 2012L, 2012L, 2013L, 
2013L, 2014L, 2014L, 2015L, 2015L, 2016L, 2016L), conm = c("penney (j c) co", 
"penney (j c) co", "penney (j c) co", "penney (j c) co", "penney (j c) co", 
"penney (j c) co", "penney (j c) co", "penney (j c) co", "penney (j c) co", 
"penney (j c) co", "penney (j c) co", "penney (j c) co", "penney (j c) co", 
"penney (j c) co", "penney (j c) co", "sonic corp", "sonic corp", 
"sonic corp", "sonic corp", "sonic corp", "sonic corp", "sonic corp", 
"sonic corp", "sonic corp", "sonic corp", "sonic corp", "sonic corp", 
"sonic corp", "sonic corp", "cascade bancorp", "cascade bancorp", 
"cascade bancorp", "cascade bancorp", "cascade bancorp", "cascade bancorp", 
"cascade bancorp", "cascade bancorp", "cascade bancorp", "cascade bancorp", 
"cascade bancorp", "cascade bancorp", "cascade bancorp", "cascade bancorp", 
"cascade bancorp", "cascade bancorp", "cascade bancorp", "cascade bancorp", 
"cascade bancorp", "cascade bancorp", "cascade bancorp", "cascade bancorp", 
"cascade bancorp", "cascade bancorp")), row.names = c(NA, -53L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Data 2:

```
data <- structure(list(Filled_Ticker2LP = c("SONC", "SONC", NA, "JCP", 
"JCP", "JCP", "SONC", "SONC", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "SONC", 
"JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "SONC", "JCP", "JCP", "SONC", "JCP", "JCP", 
"JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", 
"JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "JCP", "SONC"), publishYear = c(2005L, 2005L, 
2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 
2006L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
2011L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2015L, 2015L, 2016L), CO_1_Name = c(" sonic corp", 
" sonic corp", " cascade bancorp inc.", " jc penney company inc", 
" jc penney company inc", " jc penney company inc", " sonic corp", 
" sonic corp", " jc penney company inc", " jc penney company inc", 
" jc penney company inc", " jc penney company inc", " sonic corp", 
" jc penney company inc", " jc penney company inc", " jc penney company inc", 
" sonic corp", " jc penney company inc", " jc penney company inc", 
" sonic corp", " jc penney company inc", " jc penney company inc", 
" jc penney company inc", " macy's incorporated", " macy's incorporated", 
" jc penney company inc", " macy's incorporated", " macy's incorporated", 
" jc penney company inc", " apple inc", " apple inc", " macy's incorporated", 
" jc penney company inc", " jc penney company inc", " jc penney company inc", 
" sonic corp")), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x55603dbefe00>, row.names = c(NA, 
-36L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2):

If we need to join by a condition, one option is to `split` based on the occurrence of `NA` in the 'data' for that specific column, then use `map2` to do the join

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
data %>% 
   mutate(
     CO_1_Name = str_trim(CO_1_Name)
  ) %>% 
   group_split(grp = is.na(Filled_Ticker2LP), keep = FALSE) %>% 
   map2_dfr(list(setNames('tic', "Filled_Ticker2LP"), 
             setNames( "conm", "CO_1_Name")), ~
    left_join(.x, comp, by = c(.y, "publishYear" = "fyear")))
```